# How do they know the TNT equivalent of the meteor explosion over Vermont?

Tags: meteor, atmospheric-effects, planetary-science

I've seen several reports of this meteor explosion, below are two.

Was there infrasound recordings of the pressure wave, or were weak, local seismic signals recorded, or it this just a ballpark estimate based on circumstantial evidence?

- Bangor Daily News: [Meteor exploded over Vermont with force of **440 pounds** of TNT](https://bangordailynews.com/2021/03/10/news/new-england/meteor-exploded-over-vermont-with-force-of-440-pounds-of-tnt/)
- Sputnik News: [Yield of Fireball Explosion Above Vermont Rated at **200 Kilo(grams)** of TNT - Video](https://sputniknews.com/us/202103111082318281-yield-of-fireball-explosion-above-vermont-rated-at-200-kilos-of-tnt-video/)

Comment: related (and unanswered) in Earth Science SE: [Was the “'Bama Boom” even recorded by infrasound or by seismic detectors?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/12749/6031)

Answer (score 3):

According to [NASA Meteor Watch Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/NasaMeteorWatch/), they:

> obtained infrasound measurements from 3 nearby stations - the
> amplitudes and durations of the signals put the energy of the fireball
> fragmentation at 440 pounds (200 kilograms) of TNT.

Here is an image of the infrasound:

[image]

From [this news story](https://www.foxbangor.com/news/item/14714-huge-fireball-lights-up-night-sky-meteor-could-be-seen-throughout-northeast/?tv-channel=wvii),

> A man in Canton, Maine said there was a delay of several minutes from
> the time he saw the fireball until heard a loud boom. He said it shook
> his home unlike anything he experienced before.

It all makes me wonder [How loud was the asteroid that killed the dinosaurs?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40602/how-loud-was-the-asteroid-that-killed-the-dinosaurs)

Further reading on infrasound detectors monitoring space:

- [What is used to monitor objects burning up in the atmosphere on descent?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26359/12102)
- [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/49999/12102) to *What local pressure changes would a starship launch on Mars cause?*

and others:

- [What efforts have been made to separate the microseismic events related to wind-related ocean waves from the components of volcanic origin?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/2487/6031)
- [Project Mogul: Does upper atmosphere indeed have a sound waveguide channel?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/923/6031)

Comment: Thanks for tracking this down! I hope you don't mind I added some additional links, the one about Mars includes an image of an infrasound detector; they're funny looking things.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  It looks like I have some reading to do now!